# Option for sharing questions on social

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign

Earlier in beta there used to be option to share the question on social/networking site, but now it has been removed. Is it intentional or are there any plans to reintroduce it later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are still there if the question has no answer, but disappears once there's at least one answer. This is true for **all** sites including Stack Overflow.

This has been asked before on http://meta.stackoverflow.com (I can't find the link right now), and Jeff said that it wasn't going to happen for the existing sites.
[image]

Comment: Thanks I forgot to look at the bottom :-|